# PHP output of DIVs from arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I can't get the desired output placing the `div`'s correctly from the arrays. I can't figure out the logic of how and where get and place the variables.

I have spent 5+ hours on various *if...else loops* setting and unsetting variables etc. but I just can't seem to understand the *logic* to get the desired output... Hoping some kind person will help as my brain is boiling.

Php Code:

```
$A = array(1,1,2,3,3,3);
$B = array(1,2,NULL,1,2,3);
$C = array('Title1','lorem','Title2','Title3','dolor','sit');

$LEN = count($A);
$i = 0;

while ($i < $LEN) {
$i++;

// Collecting the data here into a variable by looping through the arrays. 
// I have tried multiple things, like a bunch of IF statements, checking if
// $C is NULL etc. but it never works. Too complicated.
}
```

Result expected:

```
<div>
    <div>Title1</div>
    <div>lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title3</div>
    <div>dolor</div>
    <div>sit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your arrays are not the same length... how are you reading them (i.e. why are you ignoring `ipsum`?)

Comment: Doh, ignore the impsum. I was trying to simplify my problems and  managed to add one too many. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

I might think about making an empty storage array to save your values into and then implode that new array:

```
# Pattern array
$pattern =  [1,1,2,3,3,3];
# Value array
$array   =  ['Title1','lorem','Title2','Title3','dolor','sit'];
# Create a storage array
$new     =   [];
# Loop the pattern array
foreach($pattern as $i => $placement) {
    # Ignore if there is an empty placement
    if(empty($placement))
        continue;
    # See if there is a matching value in the same place as the pattern array
    elseif(isset($array[$i]))
        # Store this value, make sure to keep track of the placement
        $new[$placement][]  =   $array[$i];
}
# Sort the new array so it's in order from low to high
ksort($new);
# Loop this new array and implode the placement arrays
foreach($new as $rows) {
    echo '<div>'.PHP_EOL."\t<div>".implode('</div>'.PHP_EOL."\t<div>", $rows).'</div>'.PHP_EOL.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Your array `$A` will output (as you expect):

```
<div>
    <div>Title1</div>
    <div>lorem</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Title3</div>
    <div>dolor</div>
    <div>sit</div>
</div>
```

Your array `$B` would produce (with the understanding that `NULL` has no placement and therefore ignored):

```
<div>
    <div>Title1</div>
    <div>Title3</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>lorem</div>
    <div>dolor</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>sit</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And voilà:

```
$data = [
    ['Title1' => ['lorem']],
    ['Title2' => []],
    ['Title3' => ['dolor', 'sit']]
    ];

foreach ($data AS $value) {
    foreach($value AS $k => $v) {
        echo '<div>' . "\r\n";
        echo '<div>' . $k . '</div>' . "\r\n";
        if (count($v)) {
            foreach($v AS $item) {
                echo '<div>' . $item . '</div>' . "\r\n";
            }
        }
        echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand the significance of the values in `$B` or the reason for your data structure but here is my solution for what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
// These values define which parent div the text belongs in. 
// (first, second, or third here)
$A = array(1,1,2,3,3,3); 

// These values define which child div the text belongs in.
// The NULL value aligns with the element that is an only child of the second div, 
// it is the only one so no need to say or ask which one and thus the "which" is NULL
$B = array(1,2,NULL,1,2,3);

// These values are obvious
$C = array('Title1','lorem','Title2','Title3','dolor','sit');

$result = render($A,$B,$C);

function render(array $parentIndices, array $childIndices, array $values){
    $sorted = [];

    foreach($values as $i => $text){
        $sorted[$parentIndicies[$i]][$childIndicies[$i]] = "$text";
    }

    $output = "";
    foreach($sorted as $parent){
        $output .= "<div>\n";
        foreach($parent as $child){
            $output .= "\t<div>$child</div>\n";
        }
        $output .= "<\div>\n";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

I didn't add any checks to make sure the values in the arrays conform to the pattern so

```
render([1,1],[1,1],['first','second']);
```

will produce only this

```
<div>
    <div>second</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to understand how php arrays work

this will solve your issue and get your desired output:

```
<?php

$A = array(1,1,2,3,3,3);
$B = array(1,2,NULL,1,2,3);
$C = array('Title1','lorem','Title2','ipsum','Title3','dolor','sit');

?>

<html>
<div>
    <div><?php echo $C[0]?></div>
    <div><?php echo $C[1]?></div>
</div>
<div>
<div><?php echo $C[3]?></div>
</div>
<div>
<div><?php echo $C[4]?></div>
<div><?php echo $C[5]?></div>
<div><?php echo $C[6]?></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: He have a different logic in mind, he don't want to place the array values so easily.